# Springboot + JPA: catch DataIntegrityViolationException vs check COUNT(field)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Good morning,

I am creating a new user, and it's email must be unique. I have declared it as so in the User entity.

I am wondering whether it is better (quicker/best practice) to catch a DataIntegrityViolationException when the user is being created in the DB or if it is better to check if the user exists: select count(*) from User u where u.email=? for example.

I am working in SpringBoot, using MySQL and JPA.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: The business Logic should handle that before the database throws the exception, so I would suggest to check if the `emailId` already exists if so send a proper response else insert the user

Comment: @Avi Yes, but the point is: is it more efficient to check and if it does no exist create the user, or try to create it directly and handle that exception? That is what I am pointing. Pre logic or post handling efficiency.

Comment: I understand that okay in simple term.... is executing 1 query is better than 2 query or vice versa ? is what the question and yes running 1 query is efficient but don't overlook   Over optimisation that can affect code quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference of performance might be very insignificant in that case.

What is the most important here, is to understand what happens by reading the code. You should have some code in your service layer that checks every rule defined is not violated before actually trying to proceeed in databaase. IT will be easier for new comers (and even for you in few weeks) to have a clear view of what is tested and how.

That part of code should then raise an exception with a dedicated code (for example, let's take the ID of the business rule defined by your business analysts) and in a properties, you should have a message corresponding to that rule (the message key could be the id of the rule for example).

Also, while inserting a row in this table, you could get DataIntegrityViolationException for different reasons. So, that is not a durable solution anyway.

Comment: You're welcome.

Also, to check the existence of some data, instead of counting all rows matching to your criteria, it will be more efficient in general to stop the search when you found the first row matching the criteria.
This can be done by setting the maxResults property of the query to 1 and this is exactly what Spring Data will do when you use the Derived Query Methods existsBy*.